# Mirror directories/files in one repository TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am looking to make a base build of source code and store it in Subversion, I then want to create a number of builds based on the source with key files shared/mirrored in all the subsequent builds so I can apply global updates to the shared/mirrored files of the builds and run an update so I only have to make the change once.

I know this is possible in Micorsoft VSS, does a feature like this exist in Subversion with TortoiseSVN on Windows using VisualSVN?

Comment: Normally, with SVN you save the source code not the build results. Why would you save build results instead of code?

Comment: I agree, but the base is a HTML/Web framework, not a base for a build such as an exe which will produce a package, but a number of packages that can be uploaded to a web server, so such base files such as javascript/CSS may be updated and wondered if subversion offered a share/mirror feature so you would only have to update in the base build?